# Soft copper Tubing for exterior LP Gas Lines

Tags: copper-tubing

What are the Copper Pipes Connected to the LP Gas Tanks outside coated with? And is it Code That they have to have that coating on them?

Comment: it will be laying on the ground

Comment: Various plumbing/fuel-gas codes may be selected and adopted locally with amendments. Can you pinpoint the relevant jurisdiction for us?  Many suppliers use a yellow polyethylene coating for corrosion resistance and identification.

Comment: `it will be laying on the ground`  ... do not put information in comments. add info to the question.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your question implies that you have a goal in mind; what is your goal?